# Where to get geography data?

Tags: geography

I need geography data for new website.

Data required is

- States (With names and standard abbreviations)
- ZipCode (List of zip code with all available data like where zipcode belongs to)

What would be my best source to get this data?

Any help is appreciated.

---

Thanks for all answers,

Sorry i went offline for fewdays. Yes i am talking about US zipcode data.

I think postal service data most reliable I will go with that.

Other alternative mentioned has similar and in better format data. but i think going with postal service will be the best option

Comment: Country is an important detail.  USA, UK, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(US assumed, "zip code" sort of implies the US 5-digit code, whereas "postal code" is the generic term)

**States** and their abbreviations are easy, it's on the [Postal Service website.](http://www.usps.com/ncsc/lookups/usps_abbreviations.html) (including Guam & other parts of the US that aren't states)

**Zip codes:** the Postal Service would be the authority in question, but it looks like they don't offer the basic database of zipcode <-> town, other than through an interactive one-by-one lookup. They do offer [street-level zipcode databases and other information for $ale](http://www.usps.com/ncsc/addressinfo/addressinfomenu.htm). However the Census Bureau has [a nearly identical set of information available](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/gazetteer/places2k.html). (ZCTA = ZIP Code Tabulation Areas) This has also been prepackaged more easily in a [Sourceforge project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zips/) (in their forum they claim this is from the Census Bureau data).

Answer (score 3):

For postal codes [Maxmind Free Postalcode Database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/postalcode) is the most comprehensive freely available list I know of.

For a list of countries with names and ISO ALPHA-3 codes see [Countries or areas, codes and abbreviations](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/methods/m49/m49alpha.htm).

Of course there is Wikipedia with a list and some pointers to other useful resources [Wikipedia - List of Countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a torrent that might help: http://www.mininova.org/tor/761374

I believe it's legal since it's just geographic data that's publicly available. Also, if you're looking for an access database: http://databases.about.com/od/access/a/zipcodedatabase.htm

Answer (score 1):

For what country? Australia Post has a downloadable file with all the data you're after [here](http://www1.auspost.com.au/postcodes/index.asp?sub=2). Seems like the sort of thing postal services in other countries would also provide.

Edit: was just listening to [.NET Rocks no. 437](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=437) and Bob Beauchemin mentions most of this data is available at [census.gov](http://www.census.gov/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the US (if you need states and zip codes...).

The [TIGER/Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologically_Integrated_Geographic_Encoding_and_Referencing) data is freely available. Not sure if it includes zip codes etc, but worth a look, since it's in the public domain.

Or you can check [data.geocomm.com](http://data.geocomm.com). I don't know what the exact legal status of that is though.